# How to create a static BeanTreeView in Netbeans Platform

Tags: netbeans, treeview, nodes, netbeans-platform

I want to create a static BeanTreeView in Netbeans platform, that is create a tree which nodes are already defined and they are not instances of any class but properties of a single class. For example in a class that has the following fields:

```
public int revision;
public String name;
```

The tree should have a node indicating the revision and a node indicating the name.

How should I implement the tree?

Answer (score 0):

BeanTreeView is used to display Nodes (visual representation of your "model"), and these "Nodes" are kept in the ExplorerManager associated with your JPanel hierarchy.

You may want to add Properties to your Nodes, indicating which "fields" you want to display. See, for instance: [8.1. Adding Properties to Nodes](http://vieiro.net/apuntes/swingnbrcp/swingnbrcp-ui2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good article indeed. But it means that I can't do what I asked. Am I right? I have to look for another way to represent my node? Or can I use my node's properties as a tree?